# How do I obtain the coefficients, z scores, and p-values for each fold of a k-fold cross validation in R?

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation, r-caret, glm

I'm performing 5-fold cross-validation using glm to perform logistic regression. Here is a reproducible example using the built-in cars dataset

```
library(caret)

data("mtcars")
str(mtcars)


mtcars$vs<-as.factor(mtcars$vs)
df0<-na.omit(mtcars)

set.seed(123) 
train.control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5)
# Train the model
model <- train(vs ~., data = mtcars, method = "glm",
               trControl = train.control)


print(model)

summary(model)

model$resample

confusionMatrix(model)

pred.mod  <- predict(model)
confusionMatrix(data=pred.mod, reference=mtcars$vs)
```

Output

```
> print(model)

Generalized Linear Model 

32 samples
10 predictors
 2 classes: '0', '1' 

No pre-processing
Resampling: Cross-Validated (5 fold) 
Summary of sample sizes: 25, 26, 25, 27, 25 
Resampling results:

  Accuracy   Kappa    
  0.9095238  0.8164638

> summary(model)

Call:
NULL

Deviance Residuals: 
       Min          1Q      Median          3Q         Max  
-1.181e-05  -2.110e-08  -2.110e-08   2.110e-08   1.181e-05  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)  8.117e+01  1.589e+07       0        1
mpg          2.451e+00  5.979e+04       0        1
cyl         -3.908e+01  2.947e+05       0        1
disp        -1.927e-02  8.518e+03       0        1
hp           3.129e-01  2.283e+04       0        1
drat        -2.735e+01  9.696e+05       0        1
wt          -1.248e+01  6.437e+05       0        1
qsec         1.565e+01  3.845e+05       0        1
am          -4.562e+01  3.632e+05       0        1
gear        -2.835e+01  5.448e+05       0        1
carb         1.788e+01  2.971e+05       0        1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 4.3860e+01  on 31  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 7.2154e-10  on 21  degrees of freedom
AIC: 22

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 25

> model$resample
   Accuracy     Kappa Resample
1 0.8571429 0.6956522    Fold1
2 0.8333333 0.6666667    Fold2
3 0.8571429 0.7200000    Fold3
4 1.0000000 1.0000000    Fold4
5 1.0000000 1.0000000    Fold5


> confusionMatrix(model)
Cross-Validated (5 fold) Confusion Matrix 

(entries are percentual average cell counts across resamples)
 
          Reference
Prediction    0    1
         0 50.0  3.1
         1  6.2 40.6
                            
 Accuracy (average) : 0.9062


> pred.mod  <- predict(model)
> confusionMatrix(data=pred.mod, reference=mtcars$vs)
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction  0  1
         0 18  0
         1  0 14
                                     
               Accuracy : 1          
                 95% CI : (0.8911, 1)
    No Information Rate : 0.5625     
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 1.009e-08  
                                     
                  Kappa : 1          
                                     
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : NA         
                                     
            Sensitivity : 1.0000     
            Specificity : 1.0000     
         Pos Pred Value : 1.0000     
         Neg Pred Value : 1.0000     
             Prevalence : 0.5625     
         Detection Rate : 0.5625     
   Detection Prevalence : 0.5625     
      Balanced Accuracy : 1.0000     
                                     
       'Positive' Class : 0
```

This all works fine, but I'd like to obtain the summary(model) information for each fold(meaning the coefficients, p valuess, z scores, etc that you get when performing summary() ),
as well as the sensitivity and specificity for each fold if possible. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is an interesting question. The values you are looking for cannot be obtained directly from the `model` object, but can be recalculated by knowing which observations of training data are part of which fold. This info can be extracted from the `model` if you specify `savePredictions = "all"` in the `trainControl` function. With the prediction for each k fold you can do something like this:

```
#first of all, save all predictions from all folds
set.seed(123) 
train.control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5,savePredictions = 
"all")
# Train the model
model <- train(vs ~., data = mtcars, method = "glm",
           trControl = train.control)

#now we can extract the statistics you are looking for
fold <- unique(pred$Resample)
mystat <- function(model,x){
pred <- model$pred
df <- pred[pred$Resample==x,]
cm <- confusionMatrix(df$pred,df$obs)
control <- trainControl(method = "none")
newdat <- mtcars[pred$rowIndex,]
fit <- train(vs~.,data=newdat,trControl=control)
summ <- summary(model)
z_p <- summ$coefficients[,3:4]
return(list(cm,z_p))
}
stat <- lapply(fold, mystat,model=model)
names(stat) <- fold
```

Note that by specifying `method="none"` in `trainControl` force `train` fit the model to the entire training set without any resampling or parameter tuning.
in this form, it is not a beautiful function, but it does what you want and you can always adapt it to make it more general.